# ccs3 property backgroundsize:cover mechanism

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

I have used backgroundsize:cover for image  its doing work perfectly but the problem is how to get after image size which is at on any screen size for this .

I want calculation to get image rendered height and width , i have original image height and width , screen size with me

Answer (score 1):

```
var screenWidth = 1366; //width of screen or element need to show
var screenHeight = 768;//heightof screen or element need to show
var originalImageWidth = 800; // original image width
var originalImageHeight = 600; // original image height

var backgroundHeight,backgroundWidth;

//default scale by height of screen 
backgroundHeight = screenHeight ;
backgroundWidth= backgroundHeight * originalImageWidth / originalImageHeight;
if ((screenWidth - backgroundWidth) > 0) {//if width of scale images is smaller screen show, begin scale by width
    backgroundWidth = screenWidth;
    backgroundHeight = screenWidth * originalImageHeight / originalImageWidth;
}
```

Then use css background-size percent

```
$(element).css({"background-size":(backgroundWidth+"px"+" "+backgroundHeight+"px")});
```

Comment: but I think it would go with proportional values of image and screen size

Comment: screen size : $(window).height() and $(window).width();

Comment: orginal Images size can be detect with $(images).load();

Comment: I am asking about calculation part I think it will work something which seek for proportional combination of height and width of screen and original image that i now how to get image and screen size thanks for that